# jQuery to change values of progress-bar "aria-valuenow" attribute and CSS "width" property

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I have a progress bar on my page (Bootstrap) that looks like this:

```html
<div id="theprogressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-u" 
     role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75%" aria-valuemin="0" 
     aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">
```

I would like to update it via jQuery, I have already done most of the work and calculated the new value I need to put into it, but am unsure of how to target the [`aria-valuenow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-valuenow_attribute) and the `style="width: "` values.

Assuming my jQuery gives me the new value+% as a variable called `newprogress`:

```js
$('#theprogressbar'). *(please help me finish this line)* (newprogress)
```

Comment: $('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow',value+'%');   and $('#theprogressbar').attr('width',value+'%');

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
$('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow', newprogress).css('width', newprogress);
```

value default is px if you want set % follow code below

```
$('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow', newprogress).css('width', newprogress+'%');
```

Comment: thanks that was spot on and worked a treat. Note: for my own purposes I had to add newprogress+'%' to ensure it entered the width as a % rather than px.

Comment: The value for `aria-valuenow` should be without `%`. In your original question, you have a `%` in the example and also state that `newprogress` already includes `%`. That is why this answer did not add it again. But, you should not add `%` to `newprogress` and instead only add it where you set the width. From your comment, I understand you already did this. I am just commenting to make it clear for others reading this.

Comment: Probably worth adding a `Math.round(newprogress)` for the `aria-valuenow` assuming a screen reader is reading it or something like that -- that way, avoid it having to read something like `42.343233`. I don't fully know how `aria-valuenow` is used though.

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
$('#theprogressbar').attr("aria-valuenow","the new value"); 
$('#theprogressbar').attr("style","width:"+theincrementingvalue);
```

Or you could use .css in jquery http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 4):

This works better:

```
var newprogress=80;
$('#id').width(newprogress + "%").attr('aria-valuenow', newprogress);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of just pasting code, it helps if you give an explanation as to why this works. That way, you help others realise why this works.

Answer (score 2):

To set width use `width()` method of jQuery.

To access `aria-valuenow` use `attr()`.

Combining both:

```
$('#id').width(newprogress).attr('aria-valuenow', newprogress);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the attributes of this elements as:

```
$('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow',value+'%');   

and 

$('#theprogressbar').attr('width',value+'%');
```

if the value is in variable.

```
$('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow',newprogressvalue);
```